# MDX running total with cross join

Tags: mdx

### MDX newbie question

I am using the FoodMart example database to express my problem.

I need to show running total of the "Unit Sales" measure on the column
with "Month", "Year", and "Product Name" dimensions on the rows:

```
Year    Month     Product   |  Unit Sales    UnitSoldIncludngThisProdTillDate
                            |
2014    Jan        P1       |    4                4
                   P2       |    2                6
                   P3       |    0                6
        Feb        P1       |    1                7
                   P2       |    0                7
                   P3       |    3               10
2015    Jan        P1       |    7               17
```

...... and so on

Without the cross join with Product, the query runs fine.
However, joining with Product does not give what I want.

How to solve this problem?

The MDX query that I am running is

```
AGGREGATE(YTD(), [Measures].[Unit Sales])
SELECT {[Measures].[Unit Sales], MEASURES.YTDDEMO} ON 0,
NON EMPTY {[Time].[Month].Members * [Product].[ProductLevel].Members} ON 1
FROM  [TestFoodMart]
```

### Added on 10th June 2015

I have been using the correct syntax etc.

Without the Join I get the following:

```
|                  | Unit Sales | Sales To Date |
+------+-----------+------------+---------------+
| 2013 | April     |     45,049 |        45,049 |
|      | August    |     44,777 |        89,826 |
|      | December  |            |        89,826 |
|      | February  |     44,431 |       134,257 |
|      | January   |     46,313 |       180,570 |
|      | July      |     46,671 |       227,241 |
|      | June      |     45,611 |       272,852 |
|      | March     |     46,334 |       319,186 |
|      | May       |     45,085 |       364,271 |
|      | November  |     53,807 |       418,078 |
|      | October   |     43,945 |       462,023 |
|      | September |     47,964 |       509,987 |
```

With the Join I get the following:

```
                                                                | Unit Sales | YTDDEMO |
+------+-----------+---------------------------------------------+------------+---------+
| 2013 | April     | ADJ Rosy Sunglasses                         |         38 |      38 |
|      |           | Akron City Map                              |         29 |      29 |
|      |           | Akron Eyeglass Screwdriver                  |         34 |      34 |
|      |           | American Beef Bologna                       |         28 |      28 |
|      |           | American Chicken Hot Dogs                   |         25 |      25 |
|
```

As you can see, the aggregation is not working

Comment: What does this give you what did you want to have? Screenshots will help.

Comment: What I want is given in the table above, I want the output in that format

Comment: Your last screenprint does not prove that the calculation is not working. What are the YTDDEMO numbers for August? Are you expecting it to add 38 and 29, so YTDDEMO number for  Akron City Map  will be 67 ?!

Comment: Yes, I want the YTDDEMO figure to be 67 for Akron City Map

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `WITH` line of code:

```
WITH MEMBER MEASURES.YTDDEMO AS
  AGGREGATE(YTD(), [Measures].[Unit Sales])
SELECT 
  {[Measures].[Unit Sales], MEASURES.YTDDEMO} ON 0,
  NON EMPTY 
  {[Time].[Month].Members * [Product].[ProductLevel].Members} ON 1
FROM  [TestFoodMart]
```

Please be aware of the Remarks section in the `MSDN` definition of the `YTD` function: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146039.aspx

> If a member expression is not specified, the default is the current
>   member of the first hierarchy with a level of type Years in the first
>   dimension of type Time in the measure group. The Ytd function is a
>   shortcut function for the PeriodsToDate function where the Type
>   property of the attribute hierarchy on which the level is based is set
>   to Years. That is, Ytd(Member_Expression) is equivalent to
>   PeriodsToDate(Year_Level_Expression,Member_Expression). Note that this
>   function will not work when the Type property is set to FiscalYears.

If the type property of your year attribute hierarchy is not set to time, then the `YTD` function will not work.

Does this equivalent version work?

```
WITH 
  MEMBER MEASURES.YTDDEMO AS 
    Aggregate
    (
      PeriodsToDate([Time].[Year]) <<//change to what your year level is
     ,[Measures].[Unit Sales]
    ) 
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    {
      [Measures].[Unit Sales]
     ,MEASURES.YTDDEMO
    } ON 0
 ,NON EMPTY 
    {[Time].[Month].Members * [Product].[ProductLevel].Members} ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

Comment: I don't think the entire query was posted by Diptendu and that it is a syntactical issue. He says "However, joining with Product does not give what I want".

Answer (score -1):

Could you try this, I think it's only a syntax problem.

```
AGGREGATE(YTD(), [Measures].[Unit Sales])
SELECT {[Measures].[Unit Sales], MEASURES.YTDDEMO} ON 0,
NON EMPTY ([Time].[Month].Members * [Product].[ProductLevel].Members) ON 1
FROM  [TestFoodMart]
```

Comment: Wth! It is same as the script in question? How does this qualify as an answer?

Comment: I replaced the braces with brackets.